# AngularJS — injecting scope (without $) into a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In the [Material Design mdDialog documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.dialog/service/$mdDialog), I’ve noticed that they’ve passed a scope (without a prefixed dollar sign) to the `DialogController` near the bottom.

```
(function(angular, undefined){
  "use strict";
  angular
   .module('demoApp', ['ngMaterial'])
   .controller('AppCtrl', AppController);
  function AppController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var alert;
    $scope.showAlert = showAlert;
    $scope.showDialog = showDialog;
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
    // Internal method
    function showAlert() {
      alert = $mdDialog.alert({
        title: 'Attention',
        content: 'This is an example of how easy dialogs can be!',
        ok: 'Close'
      });
      $mdDialog
        .show( alert )
        .finally(function() {
          alert = undefined;
        });
    }
    function showDialog($event) {
       var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
       $mdDialog.show({
         parent: parentEl,
         targetEvent: $event,
         template:
           '<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog">' +
           '  <md-dialog-content>'+
           '    <md-list>'+
           '      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">'+
           '       <p>Number {{item}}</p>' +
           '      '+
           '    </md-list-item></md-list>'+
           '  </md-dialog-content>' +
           '  <div class="md-actions">' +
           '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
           '      Close Dialog' +
           '    </md-button>' +
           '  </div>' +
           '</md-dialog>',
         locals: {
           items: $scope.items
         },
         controller: DialogController
      });
      function DialogController(scope, $mdDialog, items) {
        scope.items = items;
        scope.closeDialog = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        }
      }
    }
})(angular);
```

I've read that `$` is a naming convention and a good way to make sure variables don't get overwritten. Why is this code failing to follow that convention? I.e in this context, how do we know when to use `$` or not, and what is the significance? I believe in this case it must be more than just the naming convention, or the authors would have chosen to use `$scope` for purposes of consistency.

NOTE: I am aware of the difference between `$scope` and `scope` in linking functions, where `scope` is pointing to a fixed set of parameters. I do not believe that is why `scope` is used in this context, but feel free to let me know if I am wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats right @Freelancer. The DialogController function is a normal function and not a angular controller or angular directive controller. scope is just a name given to the argument there. It is not the injected $scope.

Comment: Thanks for the insights—Though, it is listed as a controller via $mdDialog.show({controller: DialogController}); ?

Comment: And, erm, if it's not a controller—what exactly is it doing? :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the docs are inconsistent here - while being correct at the same time.

The `scope` and `$scope` here will be the same, but I only figured that out after reading the source code. The culprit line is inside [`InterimElement`](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/786b0ed3652b7460c2c802efa1aa79972bd96f5d/src/core/services/interimElement/interimElement.js#L353) where `locals` are extended by `options` which in turn have a `scope` property.

```
 return showDone = compilePromise.then(function(compileData) {
              angular.extend(compileData.locals, self.options);

              element = compileData.link(options.scope);
```

I'm pretty sure that having `$scope` accessible as `scope` is only by incident and to keep things clean one should use `$scope` to refer to value provided by `$injector` like i.e. in controllers.

I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/2836) to fix the inconsistency and compiled [a pen demonstrating the usage](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGWOpZ).

Comment: You rock. Thanks a bunch! Was having tons of trouble wrapping my head around that one.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a failure over the convention, not even a failure on the snippet you got to use the modal.

The use of `scope`, and not `$scope`, it's to avoid overwrite vars inside the nested function.

The choice to place the `scope` without a dolar sign its to avoid errors for whom that will get the snippet.

Separating things, using `Controller as` syntax, for example, can help clear things up.